# Linq to Objects - converting query form to dot notation when let clause is involved

Tags: c#, linq

While reading Linq to Objects from msdn I got a sample query https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546163.aspx The example was in linq query form which I tried to convert to method form. The query includes a `let` keyword. I need suggestion on how the method form I written can be optimized, more specifically how to handle `let` when converting to method form.
So far I tried this much

```
internal static string[] GetSpecificSentenceContainingParticularWords(
    string sentenceToSearch, 
    string[] WordsToMatch)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sentenceToSearch) 
        || WordsToMatch == null 
        || WordsToMatch.Count() == 0)
        return null;

    string[] sentences = sentenceToSearch.Split(new char[] { '.' });

    var returnSentences = from s in sentences
                          let w = s.Split(new char[] { ' ' })
                          where w.Distinct().Intersect(WordsToMatch).Count() 
                                == WordsToMatch.Count()
                          select s;     

    returnSentences = sentences.Where((s) =>
    {
        var a = s.Split(new char[] { ' ' }); //splitting a sentence to words
        return (a.Distinct().Intersect(WordsToMatch).Count() == WordsToMatch.Count());
    });

    return returnSentences.ToArray<string>();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you don't even need the `let` in the first place

```
var returnSentences = from s in sentences
                      where s.Split(new char[] { ' ' })
                             .Distinct()
                             .Intersect(WordsToMatch)
                             .Count() == WordsToMatch.Count()
                      select s;
```

So you could just do

```
var returnSentences = sentences.Where(s => s.Split(new char[] { ' ' })
                                            .Distinct()
                                            .Intersect(WordsToMatch)
                                            .Count() == WordsToMatch.Count());
```

Answer (score 1):

With help of [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/):

```
var returnSentences = sentences.Select(s => new {s, w = s.Split(' ')})
                .Where(@t => @t.w.Distinct().Intersect(WordsToMatch).Count() == WordsToMatch.Count())
                .Select(@t => @t.s);
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer method syntax for every scenario with the exception of this one. With method syntax you have to store your calculated value as a property on an anonymous object. With query syntax and `let` you don't have to jump through any hoops.

I would not attempt an "optimization" by converting it to method syntax.

If however you want to optimize the code beyond just converting it to method syntax, you can cut it down to one call to `Except` and one check that the result is empty.